# How to generate a deck of cards in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a card deck in C++. My approach to do this is as follows:
-Each card needs a suit and a value
-Each suit needs 13 cards

So what I decided to do is have a prefix (the suit) and a suffix (the value). Then I would generate 13 values for each suit, and store the value in an array. My problem is that my current setup just outputs "T". Here is the current code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum cardValues{joker, ace, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten};

struct card
{
    int value;
    char suit;
};

class CardDeck
{
    public:
        void create_deck(char prefix, int suffix);
        std::string deckOfCards[51];
};

void CardDeck::create_deck(char prefix, int suffix)
{
    char cardPrefix = prefix;
    int cardSuffix = suffix;

    std::string finalCard;

    for(int numberOfCardsProcessed = 0; numberOfCardsProcessed < sizeof(cardValues); numberOfCardsProcessed++){
        finalCard = cardPrefix + cardSuffix;
        deckOfCards[numberOfCardsProcessed] = finalCard;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CardDeck CD;

    card spades;
    card diamonds;
    card clubs;
    card hearts;

    spades.suit = 'S';
    diamonds.suit = 'D';
    clubs.suit = 'C';
    hearts.suit = 'H';

    CD.create_deck(spades.suit, 1);
    std::cout << CD.deckOfCards[0];
}
```

The end result would be that I would like to be able to pass an enumeration of values to the function. Doing so now produces the error "expected primary expression before ')' token". Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You create an enum but never use it for any type. Suit should also be an enum.

Comment: Just edited the post, take another look at it. Why should both the suit and the values be enums?

Comment: Don't edit a question to a different question. Start a new question.

Comment: Why not? That's what enums are there for. What's the point of your `cardValues` enum if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: `sizeof(cardValues)` this is not equal to the number of values in the enum.

Comment: @NeilKirk Sorry about that. How can I get the number of values in the enum? I want to use the enum to pass 13 integers to one function without calling the function 13 times like `CD.create_deck(spades.suit, "1"`) `CD.create_deck(spades.suit, "2")` and so forth.

Comment: You can add a final value `cardValuesEnd` for example. So long as the enum values start at 0 and don't jump any values (the default) it will work. But I'm not sure you are using it correctly. Why not just make a constant for 13? And there are only 11 values in the enum. Do you not need Jack, Queen and King cards?

Comment: How many jokers should there be?

Comment: I want to avoid the use of "magic numbers" as I think they are called. I do need a jack queen and king cards, so I will fix that. @Surt 1 joker per suit

Comment: Traditionally there are 2 jokers per pack, not 1 per suit. You can store 13 in a named constant variable so you know what it means.

Comment: I wonder why my deck here has 3 jokers ...

Comment: I would use `vector<int> n(52); iota( begin(n), end(n), 0 );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an integer to a char, you change the character to a different one.  I think you are trying to *concatenation*, which would require some kind of string.

Comment: yes, I have `std::string finalCard` which is the string that I store the char suit and int value in. Then I want to take that string and put it in an array. Will see if I can spot the error that you mentioned.

Comment: Found it. You're right, the line `finalCard = cardPrefix + cardSuffix;` is adding a string to an integer. Will update the first post with updated code once I write it.

Comment: Still doing more research, but this post helped a lot so marking it as my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can number the cards from 0 to 53.
the pack is a vector containing all the numbers from 0 to 53. each number is allowed only once.

Now we take card `n`

if n is 52 or 53 then is a joker

for the rest of the cards:

card value should be the result of `n % 13`

The number you get should give you index in the array `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A}`

card type should be the result of `n / 13`

The number you get should give you index in the array `{spade,heart,diamond,club}`

Answer (score 0):

It's must simpler to just use an integer for the card's data. It's easy to convert that to a number or a name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

class Card {
public:
  static const int NUMSUITS = 4;
  static const int NUMVALUES = 13;
  Card() { num = nextNum++; }
  int   nSuit()  { return num / NUMVALUES; }
  int   nValue() { return num % NUMVALUES + 1; }
  const char *sSuit()  { return suits[nSuit()]; }
  const char *sValue() { return values[nValue() - 1]; }
  void  print()  { std::cout << sValue() << " of " << sSuit(); }
  void  set(int n) { num = n; }
private:
  int num;
  static int nextNum;
  static const char *suits[NUMSUITS];
  static const char *values[NUMVALUES];
};

int Card::nextNum = 0;

const char *Card::suits[Card::NUMSUITS] = {
    "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"
};
const char *Card::values[Card::NUMVALUES] = {
    "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
    "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"
};

class Deck {
public:
  static const int NUMCARDS = Card::NUMSUITS * Card::NUMVALUES;
  Deck() : top(0) {
    seed = std::chrono::system_clock
              ::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  }
  void shuffle() {
    std::shuffle(cards, cards + NUMCARDS,
                 std::default_random_engine(seed));
  }
  Card nextCard() {
    if (top >= NUMCARDS) {;} // error
    return cards[top++];
  }
private:
  Card cards[NUMCARDS];
  int top;
  unsigned seed;
};

int main() {
  Deck deck;
  deck.shuffle();
  for (int i=0; i<Deck::NUMCARDS; i++) {
    Card c = deck.nextCard();
    c.print();
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `static const char *const`?

Comment: @NeilKirk Basically what I've done is necessary, what you suggest is optional, but maybe a good idea. :-) .

Comment: To clarify for anyone reading this, the `const char *Card::suits[Card::NUMSUITS] = {` and the following definition must be in exactly one .cpp file, whereas the class definitions would go in a header file. And I'd prefer not to have the static members in the class definition at all.